# dataframe pandas how can added new columns in batches and save progress to file or pickle

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

I have a large df in a csv/pickle . To process in chunks, I need to get chuncks that contain the full user_id information so chuncks=1000 won't do it.

The basic process is

```
df = pd.read_pickle(df_pickle_location)
df['new_col1'] = df.apply(lambda row: calculate_absolute_days_since_first_order(df, row), axis=1)
df['new_col2'] = df.apply(lambda row: calc_days_since_last_ordered(df, row), axis=1)
```

how can I spilt the loaded df to by users,  process individual user_ids rows each time and save the process to the file so I can continue in another time?

Comment: A bit more of light on the context and data would be helpful. We don't understand what you mean by *"how can I spilt the loaded df to by users"*.

Comment: sorry, I thought the tag pandas would help in context

Comment: Context, not as in pandas but what you are trying to achieve using the code. Split the df by users you say, but we don't know how to find unique user in dataframe as no context neither the data  is provided.